# Is it possible to have 2 rows in sap.m.ComboBox in sapui5?

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to have 2 row layout for ComboBox like we have 2 column layout by specifying text & additionalText ?

```
<ComboBox>
<core:ListItem key="keyvalue" text="Item" additionalText = "Price"/>
</ComboBox>
```

This arranges the text & additionalText horizontally.

How do I arrange them vertically ? Is there a way ?

I want the items to appear like an ObjectIdentifier.

Please help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The ComboBox control includes an Input element which cannot display text in the desired manner. I would go with a combination of ObjectIdentifier and a Button, probably a custom control (you can find [an example of Custom control](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/d12d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db.html) in tutorials).